# reordering rows in groups

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report where the user asked for rows to be reordered. Here's what it looks like:
[image]

However, they want the groups to be completely inverted with the innermost child first, and expanding towards the end. Sort of like this:

[image]

How could I rearrange the groups? I have tried moving them in the XML but nothing happens.

For reference I have included part of the xml with the groups:

```
<TablixRowHierarchy>
  <TablixMembers>
    <TablixMember>
      <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
      <RepeatOnNewPage>true</RepeatOnNewPage>
    </TablixMember>
    <TablixMember>
      <Group Name="naics_5">
        <GroupExpressions>
          <GroupExpression>=Fields!naics_5.Value</GroupExpression>
        </GroupExpressions>
      </Group>
      <SortExpressions>
        <SortExpression>
          <Value>=Fields!naics_5.Value</Value>
        </SortExpression>
      </SortExpressions>
      <TablixMembers>
        <TablixMember>
          <Group Name="industria">
            <GroupExpressions>
              <GroupExpression>=Fields!naics_5.Value</GroupExpression>
            </GroupExpressions>
          </Group>
          <SortExpressions>
            <SortExpression>
              <Value>=Fields!naics_5.Value</Value>
            </SortExpression>
          </SortExpressions>
          <TablixMembers>
            <TablixMember>
              <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
            </TablixMember>
            <TablixMember>
              <Group Name="industry_category">
                <GroupExpressions>
                  <GroupExpression>=Fields!industry_category.Value</GroupExpression>
                </GroupExpressions>
              </Group>
              <SortExpressions>
                <SortExpression>
                  <Value>=Fields!industry_category.Value</Value>
                </SortExpression>
              </SortExpressions>
              <TablixMembers>
                <TablixMember>
                  <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
                </TablixMember>
                <TablixMember>
                  <Group Name="insumo_o_producto_bruto">
                    <GroupExpressions>
                      <GroupExpression>= IIF(Parameters!economicVariable.Value = "pb", Fields!pbto.Value, Fields!insumo.Value)</GroupExpression>
                    </GroupExpressions>
                  </Group>
                  <SortExpressions>
                    <SortExpression>
                      <Value>= IIF(Parameters!economicVariable.Value = "pb", Fields!pbto.Value, Fields!insumo.Value)</Value>
                    </SortExpression>
                  </SortExpressions>
                  <TablixMembers>
                    <TablixMember>
                      <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
                    </TablixMember>
                    <TablixMember>
                      <Group Name="articulo">
                        <GroupExpressions>
                          <GroupExpression>=Fields!articulo.Value</GroupExpression>
                        </GroupExpressions>
                      </Group>
                    </TablixMember>
                  </TablixMembers>
                </TablixMember>
              </TablixMembers>
            </TablixMember>
          </TablixMembers>
        </TablixMember>
      </TablixMembers>
    </TablixMember>
    <TablixMember>
      <KeepWithGroup>Before</KeepWithGroup>
    </TablixMember>
  </TablixMembers>
</TablixRowHierarchy>
```

The grouping looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want your grouping to remain the same but just want to have your detail row at the top.

I don't know how you'd do that in the XML either but I think you could right-click on the left cell for the detail row and **Insert Row --> Outside Group - Below**. Go to the cell below that was just created and repeat for the next 2 groups.

[image]

You resulting table should look like this:

[image]

Then copy your expression to the new rows and delete the old rows.

[image]